# Returning exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to return exceptions from a method, like this:

```
Exception f()
{
    try
    {
        // Do something.
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e;
    }
}
```

I know that this is considered bad practice, but are there any technical reasons to avoid this?

EDIT: This is not the same question as [Is it bad practice to return Exceptions from your methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973292/is-it-bad-practice-to-return-exceptions-from-your-methods).  I am asking about **technical** reasons, not best practices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it bad practice to return Exceptions from your methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973292/is-it-bad-practice-to-return-exceptions-from-your-methods)

Comment: It is not bad practice.  The program can test for null indicating no errors, but it is kind of backwards and can be confusing.  If I used your code I would make sure that it is documented very well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973292/is-it-bad-practice-to-return-exceptions-from-your-methods . Here is a brief explanation

Comment: It's not possible to say whether this is good or bad without knowing context in which such function is going to be used.

Answer (score 2):

There are no 'technical' reasons to avoid this. That is, the .Net framework will happily support this type of arrangement.

Also be aware that throwing exceptions incurs a performance penalty, so avoid relying on throwing exceptions for your normal control flow. They should only be used when something has genuinely gone wrong.

It's also fine to instantiate an exception without throwing it:

```
Exception f()
{
    return new Exception("message");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some reasons that you may want to rethink that design.

Firstly, `new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);` does not  produce your exception stack trace is not generated until you `throw` it. This may confuse debugging efforts further down the stack. The stack trace will literally be lying.

Secondly, Exception is heavier than some sort of status enum to indicate what type of error occurred. It is hard to see what benefit you are getting out of the response object being of type exception. It presumably requires the caller to subsequently perform a bunch of `if (response is FileNotFoundException) ....` and decide what they want to do for each.

This means that you lose the ability to differentiate between expected exceptions and unexpected exceptions in a given function. Take a well understood unique constraint violation. Somewhere within your call, or something you call, an insert statement is rejected by the DBMS because of another record having this value. Depending on your use case, this is either an exceptional circumstance indicating something somewhere went very wrong (eg, a corrupt data file), or a result in its own right (eg, a booking system that allocated a seat to someone else between showing you its availability and you accepting). In the first case, you would want your caller to bubble that up to the point in the application which knows what to do about that. In the second, you can safely return that for the caller to do its business.

Thirdly, it is a violation of the principle of least astonishment. Exceptions, by design, are bail out by default. Unless I explicitly catch an exception, it will bail out of my method, excecuting the stuff in my except and finally blocks, nicely calling dispose for me at the end of any using blocks and repeat in my method's caller. What it will never do is execute the code of mine that might be relying on the results of that method call.

Your design here is ignore by default. Unless I explicitly check the result and choose to throw, it will carry on executing my code. Consider this contrived example:

```
Exception error;
error = GetData(out data);
if (error is DbException) return error;
if (error is ArgumentOutOfRangeException) return error;
// if (error is ....... etc
error = ApplyChangesToData(data);
// if (error is ....... etc
error = SaveData(data);
// if (error is ....... etc
```

Now the stakes are high if I miss something, because my partially constructed data object may then make its way through the ApplyChangesToData method and then get saved back to the database in corrupted form. This could be as simple as you not anticipating that internally GetData hits a SocketException or an OutOfMemoryException. It isn't just making your abstraction a bit leaky, it means that unless you do have a leaky abstraction, your code cannot be safely written. My code has to know whether you are talking to SqlServer or Oracle or Mongo or whatever so I can anticipate all the possible exceptions you may retun and include them in my if lines. Of course I could put an else in and throw any exception object, but presumably you don't want to do this or you wouldn't be catching it in the first place.

On the other hand, if you were allowing the exceptions to bubble up, and I was confident in what such an exception meant in my context and could still meaningfully carry on, I still have the option of catching that exception and reacting to or suppressing it.

The only exception (pun unintended) that I can think of is at the edge of an API service layer, where you might want to log the exception then return a generic "something went wrong on the server" rather than blab your dirty laundry and expose security sensitive information over a public facing endpoint.

I hope I have convinced you (or , if not, at least someone in the future reading this suggestion) not to go down that dragon-filled path.